# Why does jQuery val() return empty/object

Tags: jquery

I am working on a form that automatically calculates profit of a user, based on the input. Here's my html form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inv_amount').keyup(function() {
    var invAmount = $(this).val();
    var profit = $('#profitPercent').val();
    var profCalc = +invAmount + ((profit / 100) * invAmount);
    $('#exp_earning').val(profCalc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inv_amount" class="control-label">Amount to Invest:</label>
    <input type="text" name="inv_amount" id="inv_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter an amount" required="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exp_earning" class="control-label">Expected Earning:</label>
    <input type="text" name="exp_earning" id="exp_earning" class="form-control" placeholder="Your expected earning" disabled="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="profitPercent" id="profitPercent" value="12">
  </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

The profit calculates properly, and it is displayed in the form, but when I inspect the form, the `exp_earning` returns empty. I've also checked using console.log() and I found out that it was returning an object, instead of the value.

**ANOTHER EDIT :** There are two things I will really like to know.

1. Why does the value of `#exp_earning` return empty when I try to submit the form, even when it is visible in the browser.
2. Why does the value show as an object when I try to view it in my browser console using `var outPut = $('#exp_earning').val(profCalc); console.log(outPut);` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to validate using php `empty()`.

Comment: I type `1000` and get `1120`. For the benefit of those of use who are not brokers, could you please explain why 1120 is not the expected output, what the expected out is and how it all relates to jQuery.val()?

Comment: On Chrome it works:  [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ubkvvwh5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `#exp_earning` field has the `disabled` attribute set on it. This means that it will be excluded from the request when the form is submit.

To fix the issue, simply remove the `disabled` attribute. If you do not want the user to be able to edit the value, use `readonly` instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inv_amount').keyup(function() {
    var invAmount = $(this).val();
    var profit = $('#profitPercent').val();
    var profCalc = +invAmount + ((profit / 100) * invAmount);
    $('#exp_earning').val(profCalc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inv_amount" class="control-label">Amount to Invest:</label>
    <input type="text" name="inv_amount" id="inv_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter an amount" required="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exp_earning" class="control-label">Expected Earning:</label>
    <input type="text" name="exp_earning" id="exp_earning" class="form-control" placeholder="Your expected earning" readonly="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="profitPercent" id="profitPercent" value="12">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Changing the attribute to `readonly="true"` works for the server-side validation. But why does it show as an object when I inspect it in console?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're putting in the `console.log()` call

Comment: I've done `var outPut = $('#exp_earning').val(profCalc); console.log(outPut)`, and it returned an object. Moreso, when I try to inspect the element in DOM, I don't see the new value.

Comment: `output` is a jQuery object. That's why you see an object. If you want to get the value use `console.log(profCalc)` or `console.log($('#exp_earning').val());`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @SamuelAsor Why is this the accepted answer? The question does not mention anything about submitting the form (which is apparently not designed to be submitted but a placeholder for client-side calculations), plus it doesn't seem that the `disabled` attribute prevents the control from being populated, as the snippet in the question illustrates.

Comment: Well, there were two reasons why I asked the question... 1. Why the input was returning `empty` when submitted _(changing the attribute to `readonly=true` solved that)_. 2. I wanted to know why an object was being returned in my browser console _(@RoryMcCrossan answered in comments)_. For me, marking this as the accepted answer was just the "proper" thing to do. Thanks for your explanation in your answer tho.

Comment: @SamuelAsor Alright. But, at least, please edit the question to reflect the real question you wanted to ask and this answer solves. Otherwise it'll be confusing for whoever comes here in the future asking for information about `jQuery.val()` and finds an accepted answer about something different.

Comment: I just did that now, @ÁlvaroGonzález. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have made that field disabled. Please remove `disabled="true"` and than try.

If you want that user can not change this field than in this can you can add attribute `readonly="readonly"`.

I Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this:

```
$('#exp_earning').val(profCalc);
```

... returning an object is the expected behaviour, as [documented](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value):

> `.val( value )` Returns: `jQuery`

As the browser DOM inspector, it'll normally show the actual HTML attributes, which do not necessarily reflect the value of the DOM properties.

Finally, the [`disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled) prevents the `<input>` from being submitted (among other actions):

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not available for interaction. In particular, the click event will not be dispatched on disabled controls. Also, **a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form**.